# how to update or delete category tree data

Tags: category, template, upgrade, sku, delete

The query is the following. I want to update this field in magento, but only accept or replace the new values ​​to be entered with the values ​​that already exist, doing it massively using a template, but when doing so, it only adds the new values, it does not delete me the previous data

Is there a way to remove the already existing data from this field in bulk?

[image]